# Maximum row-size exceeds in sql server error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Recently one of out `SSIS packages` failed due to below error.

> "Cannot create a row of size 8208 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum size of 8060"

I understood this is because the row-size is exceed the limit. Could someone please clarify the below questions

1. We found there are 650 records in the table which exceeds the `row-size` limit. How sql server allows to insert these `records.` (we have the issue in two packages but only one is failing.)
2. Is there any factors other than row-size causes the failure?
3. what is the best possible solution for this issue?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The row size is determined by the types of the columns that you have in your table, but not exactly on how much data you store in these columns.

By that, I guess the issue and the error message are self-explanatory. You can refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.105).aspx) documentation for various limits that need to be adhered to when you are using MS SQL Server in particular.

**(OR)**

There can be a different explanation as per the scenario specified, there can be a `COLUMN` that could've deleted\altered. This can be a possibility too!

Comment: thanks. But how sql-server allows the records to be inserted before? i am sure there were no table schema changes.

Comment: So no schema changes huh, getting difficult to explain why now!